# String variable 'was not declared' header c++

Tags: c++

Why does eclipse say that 'name' was not declared in this scope? the above one is my header, the other one is my .ccp

```
#include<string>
class Characters {
public:
std::string characters(int);
std::string name;
};



string characters(int x){

ofstream characters;
characters.open("characters.txt");
while (characters >> name){
return name;
}
}
```

Comment: Apologies for the not-quite-correct duplicate; the linked question lists code that would not actually reproduce the error. But the OP did the same error as you did *in the code actually compiled*, and the accepted answer is right on the spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be

```
string Characters::characters(int x){

   ofstream characters;
   characters.open("characters.txt");
   while (characters >> name){
      return name;
   }
}
```

Comment: thx missed that part :p

Answer (score 2):

The reason is you didn't mention that, this is an implementation of a class method so you need to specify it like below:

Change:

```
string characters(int x)
```

to:

```
string Characters::characters(int x)
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is not in a method of the `Characters` class. Thus it can't reference members of that class.

The code also makes almost no sense, but that's another matter of course.